# Why is $x=-\sqrt{\tan(y)}$ rejected when differentiating $y=\tan^{-1}x^2$?

Tags: calculus

I will work through the problem to identify my issue.

$$y=\tan^{-1}(x^2)$$

$$\tan(y) = x^2$$

From this we know that:

$$\sin(y)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$$ and $$\cos(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^4}}$$

$$x=\pm \sqrt{\tan(y)}$$

My textbook only continues with the + route. Why would the − route be rejected here?
$$\dot{x}=\pm \frac{\sec^2(y)}{2\sqrt{\tan(y)}}=\pm \frac{1+x^4}{2(\pm x)} $$

$$\dot{y}=\pm \frac{2x}{1+x^4}$$

I graphed both $y$ and $\dot{y}$ and sure enough the + route is indeed the slope function while the - route is not, so I'm convinced that the - route should indeed have been rejected but I can't see how you would know to reject it.

Comment: Why not directly differentiate to get $\sec^2 y \ \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{(\sec(\arctan x^2))^2}$?

Comment: You can then draw a right triangle to find $\sec(\arctan x)$.

Comment: Who advised you to use $\dot x$ for $\mathrm dx/\mathrm dy$ and $\dot y$ for $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ in the same exercise? Is this practice from a textbook?

Comment: @DavidK I remember my highschool teacher used to do that but he did warn us that he was doing it out of laziness and he told us to make sure to write out the full dy/dx in our exams. Why do you ask btw ? What were your thoughts on it ?

Comment: @TobyMak I'm not sure what right triangle you are refering to. What is the angle ? y ? x ? $x^2$ ?

Comment: The dot notation works OK when it consistently signifies $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}$, usually in physics. I think Newton used it for $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$. Switching variables during a single exercise seems like a mistake waiting to happen, though in this particular case (since it only shows up once each way) the danger is less: I knew what you meant.

Comment: For the right triangle, let one leg be length $1$, the other leg length $x^2$. Then one of the angles is $\arctan(x^2)$. You can then easily find $\cos(\arctan(x^2))$ (and thereby $\sec(\arctan(x^2))$) and the only formulas you need to remember are the Pythagorean Theorem and SOHCAHTOA.

Comment: @Kantura Does this make sense? https://imgur.com/gallery/KdCq8zN

Comment: @TobyMak I understand now. That method bypasses the whole dx/dy stage. Great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both routes work, and they have to work, otherwise the derivative wouldn't exist in $x<0$. In fact, *you* showed that in the 2nd to last line! The $\pm$ signs cancel out in the expression for $\dot{x}$.

$$\dot{x}=\pm\frac{x^4+1}{2(\pm x)}$$

Choosing $+$:

$$\dot{x}=+\frac{x^4+1}{2x}$$

And choosing $-$:

$$\dot{x}=-\frac{x^4+1}{2(- x)}=\frac{x^4+1}{2x}$$

The important thing to remember is that you can never have a situation where the $\pm$ signs are different. This comes from choosing one of the signs in $x=\pm \sqrt{\textrm{tan}(y)}$, so e.g choosing the first $\pm$ sign to be $-$:

$$\dot{x}=-\frac{x^4+1}{2(\pm x)}$$

This means you chose $x=- \sqrt{\textrm{tan}(y)}$, so naturally the second $\pm$ sign is also $-$.

Your last line is incorrect, instead:

$$\dot{y}=\frac{2x}{x^4+1}$$

And there is no negative sign.

Comment: Oh I see now. Great , that makes sense.